# Good practice to avoid code duplication Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I have an specification interface lets call it **Spec** and two classes that implement it lets call them **ImpA** and **ImpB**. It worked great until I realized that few methods from **ImpA** and **impB** share the same implementation. 
I have tried to avoid it by declaring methods in **Spec** with default and implementing them right in it, but I'm sure that there is a better way to do it. 
Maybe some design pattern?

Comment: What about creating a new interface which is only responsible for avoiding code duplication while your actual Spec class handles business logic based interfacing without any default methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code that's duplicated doesn't use the state of the class (the instance variables), putting the code in a default method in the interface is one solution.

For more complex situations where you need to access class instance variables, you can create an additional abstract class with the common code. Then `ImpA` and `ImpB` would extend the abstract class.

Collections in Java use a bit of both. For example, `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` extend `AbstractList`, which implements `List`, which contains a few default methods.

Comment: It uses lists from other classes, but I'm thinking about making them static in class so I can access them from Interface instead of making a new abstract class. What do you think about that ?

Comment: Hard to say without more information - using static objects to communicate between classes generally makes your code harder to test and more fragile. But it really depends on the details.

Comment: I want to complete separate specification from implementation, that's the main task of this project.

Comment: You can have default methods in an interface that access state if the interface also defines accessors for the state. Of course not desirable if the said state is internal crap that should not be published.

Answer (score 3):

While you could make them `default` methods as you've proposed, another potential solution is to use the [Delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) design pattern. This means having a fourth class that is entirely for the purpose of separating the common logic. If that logic needs values to operate then they should be injected into the delegate to allow it to operate (and be tested) independently.

Personally, I find code that prefers delegation over composition to be more elegant, more testable and much more 'refactorable'. But, like many other design questions, there are many varied and valid opinions on this.

```
interface Spec { 
    void method();
}

class Imp1 implements Spec {
    private final Delegate delegate;

    public Imp1() {
        this.delegate = new Delegate(...);
    }

    public void method() {
        delegate.setContext(...);
        delegate.method();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make Spec a superclass and have ImpA and ImpB the subclasses. You can find more information [on the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: Given Spec is an interface it really shouldn't be converted to a superclass. Interfaces have a very specific purpose.